# How do i go about my next visit visa application

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not
> satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) 4.2 of
> Appendix V: Immigration Rules of visitors because:
>
> - You have applied to visit the United Kingdom for 5 days for tourism.
> - You state that you are self-employed and earn an annual income of 75,000.00 GHS  (5,548.27 GBP). You state that you do not have any
>   other income or savings.
> - You state that you intend to personally spend 1500.00 GBP on your visit to the United Kingdom. Your proposed expenditure on this trip
>   equates to over a third of your annual income. This form of
>   expenditure on a short trip of this nature is disproportionate to your
>   current circumstances which further casts doubt on your intentions and
>   whether you will leave at the end of your proposed trip.
> - Given the above I am therefore not satisfied that you have demonstrated your circumstances are as declared, which leads me to
>   doubt your intentions in travelling to the UK. I am not satisfied that
>   you are genuinely seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted under
>   the visitor route and that you will leave the UK at the end of your
>   visit. Your application is therefore refused under paragraph V 4.2 (a)
>   and (c) of the Immigration Rules.
>
> Rate of exchange 1 GBP = 13.51773 GHS reference [www.oanda.com](http://www.oanda.com) on
> 24/05/2023

Comment: This site isn't suited to giving personalised advice for individual cases. The question linked above has lots of information that is generally relevant to refusals like yours. Your refusal letter is quite clear about why the decision was made: your planned costs are very high for somebody with your stated income and savings, especially for a short trip. Unless your financial circumstances change, it's unlikely you will be granted a visa for a trip like this one. I suggest consulting with a lawyer who specialises in UK immigration/visa topics before submitting any further applications.